# Previous and next links when cycling through elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set up a simple custom slider, using the following jquery

```
var divs = $('div[class^="slide-holder-"]').hide(),
    i = 0,
    $slide = $("#banner > div");

(function cycle() { 
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(2000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);


i = ++i % divs.length;
})();
```

with the following html

```
<div id="banner">
   <div class="slide-holder-1">
      <div class="slide-1"> some content </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide-holder-2">
      <div class="slide-2"> some content </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to add previous and next links to go straight back/forward but not having any luck, I'd appreciate any help!

Cheers

Comment: What should we understand from "straight"? If the word was omitted from the last sentence, would the meaning change?

Comment: Your function definition looks incomplete there

Answer (score 0):

It is not very elegant, but adding to divs to switch forward or backward in the html:

```
<div id="banner">
   <div id="backward" style="float:left">&lt;</div>
   <div id="forward" style="float:right">&gt;</div>
   <div class="slide-holder-1">
      <div class="slide-1"> some content 1 </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide-holder-2">
      <div class="slide-2"> some content 2 </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide-holder-3">
      <div class="slide-3"> some content 3 </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and then stopping the animation, changing `i` if necessary and restarting the `cycle` works for me.

```
$(function() {

  var divs = $('div[class^="slide-holder-"]').hide(),
      i = 0,
      $slide = $("#banner > div");

  function cycle() { 
      divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
          .delay(2000)
          .fadeOut(400, cycle);
      i = ++i % divs.length;
  }

  $('#forward').click(function() {
      divs.stop(true).hide();
      cycle();
  });

  $('#backward').click(function() {
      divs.stop(true).hide();
      i = (i-2+divs.length) % divs.length;
      cycle();
  });

  cycle();

});
```

I need to make `cycle` a "visible" function for this to work.
One cannot page fast through the items, because the `fadeIn` needs to show the current element before one can page to the next, but maybe it is at least a starting point.